# Display only one product-variartion related to a product display

Tags: views, search

I am creating a view to display products on my upcoming e-shop. Following is the structure: I am using Search API for this.

[image]

When someone navigate form MEN > Half Sleev , the view should display only one color related to a tShirt. I think search_api doesn't support query alter.